# Non-react-leaflet overlay on map

Tags: z-index, react-leaflet

just getting started on react-leaflet and leaflet. After clicking on a marker I want to have a full screen overlay above the map to display a graph. But no matter how I set z-index of the  and , the overlay always lies below the map.
Couldn't find an answer as most z-index question apply to map layers etc. within the  component.

```
.overlay-wrapper {
position: fixed;
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
z-index: 200;
cursor: pointer;}
```

It should be pretty straight forward, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you able to share the rest of your code or produce a working example of this issue?

Comment: it's all depends on the z-index of your map container, you need to have it lower also try to use    `position: absolute;`

Comment: OK. Turns out that the standard non-react leaflet map is set to a z-index somewhere below 400 which seems random. I had to put in 400, and it get's rendered. The react-leaflet component is set to z-index 400 exactly,z-index 401 is required for the .overlay-wrapper. The devil is in the details, I assumed 200 was enough of a z-index!

Answer (score 0):

As @andreasgroos mentioned in their comment, the z-index value needs to be high enough, i.e. 401 or higher. z-index: "2000 !important" should guarantee that the component will be rendered over the map.